# How to do dynamic reporting in TeamCity

Tags: maven, jmeter, teamcity

I have a TeamCity project that runs Jmeter via Maven in a build called "PerfRunner" under the project "Audit-Service-Performance". When it runs Jmeter produces a target dir with a report html file, index.html.

I want TeamCity to create a report tab with the latest report from the latest successful.

Folder structure relative to artifact:

```
target
-jmeter
--bin
--lib
--logs
--reports
---jmeter-deng-audit-standalone_time_stamp
----index.html
--results
--testFiles
```

The problem is that the time_stamp in meter-deng-audit-standalone_time_stamp is auto generated and therefore changes with each build.

When I try to create a report tab I do a project or build report tab I tried:

target/jmeter/**/index.html. But it doesn't generate the report tab.

The only way I can get it to work is if I address a static file for a particular build which of course wont be the latest once a new build is run.

The MVN command runs clean. How can I make it dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish this `index.html` page as the [build artifact](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Build+Artifact). If you want to share the page with the others you can go for one of the following [patterns of accessing build artifacts](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts):

```
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID/.lastFinished/index.html
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID/.lastSuccessful/index.html
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID/.lastPinned/index.html
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID/BUILD_ID:id/index.html
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID/BUILD_NUMBER/index.html
```

You can also consider using [JMeter Teamcity Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9088-jmeter) - it adds Performance Statistics tab where you can observe performance trend for last builds

[image: JMeter Teamcity Plugin]

Check out [How to Run JMeter Tests with TeamCity for Continuous Integration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-jmeter-tests-teamcity-continuous-integration) article for more information on how to configure JMeter to work with Teamcity

Comment: Thanks for this, I ended up introducing a build step that would copy the contents of the dynamically named folder to a static one that the reporting tab can pick up.